# Session Timeout on Unexpected Error or Turn Off PC in GWT

Tags: java, session, gwt

How do I set session status as Inactive on computer shutdown or pcturn off or any kind of unexpected error?

I tried using session timeout code, which has 2 minutes timeout. which is working fine, but how can I handle unexpected errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If the client doesnt tell you it's away, you are left with the timeout.

Nevertheless, you can:
- monitor navigation
- add a close window handler

If I remember correctly, there is an event on newer browsers for the screenblanker, but the session timeout is good enough in this case.